# How should I handle public (TCGA) data on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bioinformatics, aws-cli

I'm new to AWS development and studying how to use TCGA data (https://registry.opendata.aws/tcga/) on my EC2 instance.

1. `$ aws s3 ls s3://tcga-2-open/` gives me millions of files. However, the XML file http://tcga-2-open.s3.amazonaws.com shows me only 1000 entries. Is there a full list of files, hopefully describing their hierarchy, so that I can lookup the coverage of this resource?
2. All TCGA files have prefix, and they seem to be GDC UUIDs (https://docs.gdc.cancer.gov/Encyclopedia/pages/UUID/). However, some files have UUID that I cannot find from original source. Downloading 'manifest' from https://portal.gdc.cancer.gov/repository gives me a list of UUIDs and their implications. However, some UUIDs from the manifest file and from the XML file are mutually exclusive. So how do I know what file, for example, http://tcga-2-open.s3.amazonaws.com/00002fe8-ec8e-4e0e-a174-35f039c15d06/6057825020_R01C01_Grn.idat, is, when I cannot find '00002fe8-ec8e-4e0e-a174-35f039c15d06' from the ground truth manifest file?
3. Is there any step-by-step tutorial to using Open Data on AWS?

Any help to get me through this would be really appreciated.